# Asymptotics of an integral by two methods

Tags: cv.complex-variables, integration, asymptotics

This was asked in MSE, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2710270/asymptotics-of-an-integral-by-two-methods), but the answer was not satisfactory.

I want to compute the asymptotic behavior of the integral 
$$ f(K,a)=\int_0^1 (1-x)^Ke^{iKa\frac{x}{1-x}}x^2dx$$
when $K$ is large and $0<a<1$. I tried two different approaches.

1) My first idea was that the exponential, a fast-oscillating function around $x=1$, is killed by the $(1-x)^K$, and the integral should be dominated by the vicinity of $x=0$. Therefore, I put $x=y/K$ and approximate $(1-y/K)^K\approx e^{-y}$ and $\frac{x}{1-x}\approx \frac{y}{K}$ to get

$$f(K,a)\approx \frac{1}{K^3}\int_0^\infty e^{-y+iay}y^2dy=\frac{2}{K^3(1-ia)^3}.$$

2) On the other hand, the stationary phase approximation should be valid. If I write 
$$f(K,a)=\int_0^1 e^{KS(x)}x^2dx,$$
with $S(x)=\log(1-x)+iax/(1-x)$, the equation $S'(x_0)=0$ gives $x_0=1-ia$. Second derivative is $S''(x_0)=-1/a^2$.
Hence, this idea leads to
$$f(K,a)\approx e^{KS(x_0)}x_0^2\sqrt{\frac{\pi a^2}{K}}=(ia)^Ke^{K(1-ia)}(1-ia)^2a\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{K}}.$$

These two results are completely different! I need help understanding this.

Comment: Your method 1) can be made precise pretty easily, by bounding the part of the integral away from 0, and then applying Taylor expansions.  On the other hand, your method 2) is very hand-wavy.  There is no reason to think the main contribution should come from a stationary point with Re(x) = 1, since the integrand is very small except in a tiny neighborhood of x=0.

Comment: @MattYoung I favor method 1) as well, but I would like to know what is precisely the obstacle to applying a stationary phase approximation

Comment: The obstacle is that the stationary point is not close to $x=0$ (where the mass of the integrand is concentrated).  You can think of stationary phase as applying a quadratic approximation to the phase centered at the stationary point.

Comment: Another obstacle is that there is no reason to climb to the stationary point when going from $0$ to $1$: you are in a deep valley all the way, so the "mountain path" approach makes no sense. You could easily detect it yourself by noticing that the answer is predicted to be of order $e^K$, which is *much* larger than all the values of the integrand.

Comment: @fedja "makes no sense" is a bit strong, no? I can see that using the stationary point might not be the best approach, but at least it should give the right answer, no? Why does it break down? Am I not allowed to deform the contour due to some singularity?

Comment: You are allowed to deform the contour but the stationary phase will work only if you go from one side to another, so you can cross straight in the pass and never return. In this case both ends are on one side of the mountain, so you cannot make a contour deformation that gives the maximum in the saddle and  much smaller values everywhere else. Just make a color plot of the (logarithm of) the absolute value and think of how you would like to go.

Comment: In other words, it makes as much sense as using the Laplace formula with $x=0$ when finding the asymptotics of $\int_1^2e^{-Kx^2}\,dx$. IMHO, that is "no sense", but if you have a reason to think otherwise, let me know :-). Remember that almost all ready recipes always have some crucial "conditions of applicability" attached to them, which, alas, are forgotten more often than not by people who try to use them.

Comment: @fedja indeed, I was only worrying about whether the contour could be deformed to go through the saddle, I did not have a clear notion of the condition you mention of both endpoints being "on the same side of the mountain". That was very helpful, thank you.